# why music and video software on my ubuntu does not work?

Tags: linux

I had to upgrade music and videos software up to three times , but until now I can not hear music or see the video in ubuntu
Can  you help me to solve this problem ?
please share
thanks :)

Comment: What software? What error messages are you seeing? What **are** you seeing if you don't see the video?

Comment: What are you trying to play? Lady Gaga or worse?

Comment: What music and video formats?  Audio CD's or MP3 or something else?  The former is most likely supported out of the box, MP3 decoders are not shipped by default by many distros because of legal issues.  There are various repositories out there with the required software.

Comment: MAt : sound and video ... video player and rhytmbox music player..

Comment: ott : music and movie...

Comment: bram : MP3'S ,,